# Discord.py delete message in specific channel of a specific user if he sends a message in other channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a bot deleting a message in a specific channel of a specific user if he sends a message in other channel and it contains a specific word or letter

```
async def on_message(message):
  if '++' in message.content:
    user = await bot.get_user(id)
    channel = bot.get_channel(x)
    if message.author.id == 'user'
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: could you please add details ? Give us an example and what you were able to do and what you can not. Do you just want to delete the message that the author sent ?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, I want to delete all message of a user in a specific channel.

Comment: So, for example. The user sends a message in channel 1 then bot checks if the message contains '++' if its true the bot deletes all messages of this user in a channel 2

Comment: you should pass the context when you define your function, you pass it as ctx then do await ctx.message.delete()

Comment: ho ok I see what you mean, but it's not necessary because as soon as someone posts a message it will be deleted whatever the channel is. There will be no such message in channel 2 because if they send it it will be deleted.

Comment: unless you want to delete the old messages that were added before your bot

Comment: yes, old messages. For example in channel 2 the user had already sent a message before senting '++' in a channel 1. Then he sends '++' in channel 1 and bot deletes his messages in channel 2

Comment: This is not possible, as far as I know, a bot can't read the whole chat before it joined a server.

Comment: So, a bot is going to keep deleting messages of this user if he sends ++ once?

Answer (score 0):

A bot can't read a channel before it was invited to a server. You wont be able to delete old messages containing "++", however as soon as your bot is inside a server, this code will delete any message containing "++"

```
async def on_message(ctx):
    if '++' in ctx.message.content:
        await ctx.message.delete()
```